# program crashing using 2D dynamic string array in c

Tags: c, dynamic

I am having a problem with this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int num=0;
    printf("Enter number of entries: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);
    char **firstname=NULL;
    char **lastname=NULL;
    float *score=NULL;
    int i;
    firstname = malloc(num * (sizeof(char*)));
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        firstname[i] = malloc(21);
    }
    lastname = malloc(num * (sizeof(char*)));
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        lastname[i] = malloc(21);
    }
    score = ((float*)malloc(num* (sizeof(float))));
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the first name of entry %d: \n", i);
        scanf_s("%s", firstname[i], 21);
        printf("Enter the last name of entry %d: \n", i);
        scanf_s("%s", lastname[i], 21);
        printf("Enter the score of entry %d: \n", i);
        scanf_s("%f", score[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s, %s, %f", firstname[i], lastname[i], score[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have edited  the code with the suggested changes, and now it prints random characters and a random value for the first and last name, as well as the score. the code also crashes if there is more than one iteration of input (after asking for the score of the first entry, it crashes before asking for the first name of the second entry.)

Comment: first : `for (i = 0; i < num; ++i);` remove `;` (2) input part : `num` --> `i + 1` and needs `{ }`

Comment: (3) `scanf_s` needs buffer size. E.g `scanf_s("%s", firstname[i], 21);`

Comment: alright, done, thanks for pointing that out! now, unfortunately, I have another issue: it prints the output as strange characters for the first and last name, and then a random number for the score.

Comment: `&firstname[i]` remove `&`, try `scanf_s("%20s", firstname[i], 21);`

Comment: I edited the original post to reflect the changes to the code after your help.

Comment: `scanf_s("%s", firstname[i], 21);` -->`scanf_s("%s", firstname[i-1], 21);` lastname ditto. and `scanf_s("%f", score[i]);`--> `scanf_s("%f", &score[i-1]);`

Comment: the program still crashes after the first iteration of input, whether it goes to try to output, or to ask for the inputs for the next entry.

Comment: check this again:`scanf_s("%f", score[i]);` -->`scanf_s("%f", &score[i-1]);`